# How could I do this trigger delete with validations

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to the forum, i have the following problem, I want after I delete a lease table locations I go in the table films and have the column situation becomes as available, but if I have the code of the movie in the table location in another register, I still leave the column state of the table film as leased, how would I do that?

that's what I've done

```
TRIGGER `tguDelete` AFTER DELETE ON `locations` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE movies SET situation = 'available' WHERE code_location = OLD.code_location
```

I wanted to post pictures of the tables, but I'm new to the forum
Please help me!

I use phpmyadmin, and I am new to mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your trigger definition required some work. For instance - you'd want to declare the "`trigger function`" which should execute `AFTER` the `DELETE` operations on `locations` table. This is how you can do it:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tguDelete`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tguDelete` AFTER DELETE ON `locations` 
FOR EACH ROW 
-- condition for rows for which the trigger would fire WHEN (OLD.code_location <> 0)
-- DECLARE
   -- if you had things you wanted to declare
BEGIN
   -- here you do the updating of the movies table:
   UPDATE movies SET situation = 'available' WHERE code_location = OLD.code_location;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If you don't need DELIMITERS (ie: PHPMyAdmin) then skip them such as

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tguDelete`;
CREATE TRIGGER `tguDelete` AFTER DELETE ON `locations` 
FOR EACH ROW 
-- condition for rows for which the trigger would fire WHEN (OLD.code_location <> 0)
-- DECLARE
   -- if you had things you wanted to declare
BEGIN
   -- here you do the updating of the movies table:
   UPDATE movies SET situation = 'available' WHERE code_location = OLD.code_location;
END;
```

Comment: I think so, but when I run it myself from an error in when

Comment: Please update your question and add the error that you are getting. In fact you can omit it if you have no use for it and see if the trigger works.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN (OLD.code_location <> 0) DECLARE -- if you had things you wanted to de' at line 1

Comment: please comment it out by adding `--` in front of WHEN.

Comment: I killed the url at the end as this is not plsql

Comment: It works when I remove the begin and the end and also the semicolon

Comment: Thanks for the help, phpmyadmin is not good to work with triggers

Comment: Glad we could help - happy coding! Thanks for the valuable edits, @Drew.

Comment: np anytime my friend

Comment: Thanks, god bless you all